# Using AutoMapper to assist in Iterating through an Object

Tags: c#, automapper

I am having some mapping issues that I was hoping the community could assist with. I am working with `AutoMapper` version 6.0 to establish connections between objects. I have three objects (named generically since the data itself doesn't really matter) with the following structure:

```
public ObjectA {
    string field1 { get; set; }
    string field2 { get; set; }
    string field3 { get; set; }
    string field4 { get; set; }
}

public ObjectB {
    string field1 { get; set; }
    string field2 { get; set; }
    List<ObjectC> ObjectC { get; set; }
}

public ObjectC {
    string field3 { get; set; }
    string field4 { get; set; }
}
```

I have a couple maps setup like so:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {
    cfg.CreateMap<ObjectC, ObjectA>();
    cfg.CreateMap<ObjectB, ObjectA>();
});
```

Which brings me to my problem. `ObjectA` is a direct representation of a DB table and its fields, and I would like to use `ObjectB` to create check against entries in the table using `ObjectA`, and add any that do not already exist. My problem is that I do not seem to understand how to establish the proper connection between `ObjectB` and `ObjectA` via `AutoMapper` in which I check for each possible variant that `ObjectB` could create of `ObjectA`.

The end goal should turn out something like:

```
ObjectA objectA = // mapped data from ObjectB with the contents of List Item [0]
var objectAExists = _dataHandlers.GetObjectA;
if (objectAExists)
{
   // some code to return use to iterate back that this variant is in the DB already
   log.Info("ObjectA Already Exists");
}
else
{
    var results = storeContents(objectA);
    log.Info("New Contents Stored");
}
// return to top of iteration and this time process with contents using ObjectB.ObjectC[1] being used, and so on.
```

I have tried a series of approaches such as:

```
// try to iterate through each List item...
for (int i = 0; i < ObjectB.ObjectC.Count; i++) {  
    //I wanted this to map the contents like so:
    ObjectA objectA = new ObjectA() {
        Field1 = ObjectB.Field1,
        Field2 = ObjectB.Field2,
        Field3 = ObjectB.ObjectC[i].Field3,
        Field4 = ObjectB.ObjectC[i].Field4
    }
    // but I couldn't figure out how to make a similar association using AutoMapper...
}

// tried to iterate through each with a foreach loop... but was in a similar situation as above... 
foreach (var objectC in ObjectB.ObjectC)  { // some code... }

// I tried double mapping...
    var objectA = Mapper.Map<ObjectA>(ObjectB);
    objectA = Mapper.Map<ObjectA>(objectC); // new problem hits here
// when I attempted to add the data from the new mapping, it overwrote the data populated by the first mapping...
// Change '=' to '+=' wasn't possible, so that didn't help...

// altering the mapper...
   cfg.CreateMap<ObjectB, ObjectA>()
       .Include<ObjectC, ObjectA>();
```

Even tried using type converters... but ran into another wall. Needless to say, I am running low on ideas and the AutoMapper documentation does not seem to provide enough information to help work this problem out. Any word of advice that could point me to the solution would be greatly appreciated...

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: `// problem should be obvious... ` it isn't. Can you provide an actual example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: @stuartd I did provide an example of what I am trying to do where I state "the end goal". As for the "should be obvious", I'll update that. short version: it overwrote the data from the first mapping

Comment: If you have to jump through hoops to do something with AutoMapper, then do it without.

Comment: @GertArnold In all honestly, if I didn't have to figure out how to do this with AutoMapper, I wouldn't be asking. This particular assignment requires it

Comment: *This particular assignment requires it* So is this homework or some academic exercise? Of course it may be a fun challenge to try and peel a potato with a fork, but it's not something to do on a daily  basis. Another more serious objection is that you're storing non-normalized data. ObjectB and ObjectC should be stored as such in the database in a 1:n relationship. ObjectA is full of redundancy.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what you're looking for is a mapping expression which specifies that the destination property should only be mapped if it's not already set. That way the mapping is conditional. If the destination property is not already set, it will be mapped from the source. If the destination is already populated, it won't be overwritten.

```
Mapper.Initialize(
    cfg =>
    {
        cfg.CreateMap<ObjectB, ObjectA>()
            .ForMember(src => src.field2,
                opt => opt.ResolveUsing((src, dest) => 
                    dest.field2 = dest.field2 ?? src.field2
                ));
    });
```

Comment: This is useful, but doesn't solve the problem as this is coming from `ObjectC` rather than `ObjectB`. How would I set this up so that I can map from `ObjectB` to `ObjectA`? I need the mapping to allow me to create multiple instances of `ObjectA` so that Field1 and Field2 are the same, but Field3 and Field4 will be different for each instance

Comment: I may have gotten lost in which property you were trying to map. In that case, just replace `ObjectC` above with `ObjectB`, and specify whichever property you're mapping. I'll edit it.

Comment: Truthfully it's more likely that I misunderstood the question.

Comment: Either way, this still leaves me with the same problem. I get stopped when I reach the point of `src.ObjectC[?].Field3`. The problem is with the [?] section. As this is a list of `ObjectC` within `ObjectB`. I don't know setup AutoMapper so that I can control getting back only the first, or only the second, or create new `ObjectA` for each `ObjectC` in `ObjectB`. If this isn't possible, I'll have to create some factory method to handle this.